# Entity relationships based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a table `leads` that takes on information from different sources (import, manual insert, post).

I have another table I called `dupes` which should keep track of the dupes that are removed from table `leads`.

I made a foreign key relationship between them and a `on delete` constraint. The problem is that data from `leads` table sometimes is removed for other reasons other than the record being duplicate. So I added a new column to `leads` that asks `dupes?`. If yes then its set to true and deleted, if not because its not a dupe my php sets it to false and it is deleted. So I want a relationship between `leads` and `dupes` tables to be setup where `dupes` table takes on only rows with true in `dupes?` column with a `on delete` constraint.

What kind of database relationship do I need to have to allow `dupes` table to take on only rows that are deleted from `leads` table because they were dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delete trigger in the leads table that checks the dupes? value, and inserts the row accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I just learned about Triggers some time after asking this question. It pretty much solves my problem for facilitating scrips to move data.